# How to efficiently index vectors of 2000 values in PostgreSQL and find nearest neighbours?

Tags: database, postgresql, indexing, nearest-neighbor, r-tree

I have feature vectors of more that 2000 values. For example, say, I have 10,000 vectors of 2000 decimal values each. I need to index them and find the nearest neighbours for a query vector. Can I index them using R trees in PostgreSql? If so, how can we do it? Or is there any other way or any other DB for efficiently doing this?

Comment: You'd probably have to implement your own GiST index in PostgreSQL.

Comment: How are you measuring distance, Euclidean?

Answer (score 1):

Check this out if elastic search is an option. You can do distributed searches in vector space: https://blog.mimacom.com/elastic-cosine-similarity-word-embeddings/

Answer (score 0):

An R-tree on 2000 dimensions will probably be much worse than a sequential scan.  Your best bet might be to store the table data in an index in a format preorganized for computational speed, then resign yourself to scanning the whole index.  This is what [bloom indexes](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/bloom.html) do (In concept, with the full scan of the index. The organization and computation of the data of course is different.)